# bpftrace under VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, ebpf

I'd like to run `bpftrace` under Ubuntu on VirtualBox.

Unfortunately, I get

```
$ sudo bpftrace -e 'tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_open { printf("%s %s\n", comm, str(args->filename)); }'
Kernel lockdown is enabled and set to 'confidentiality'. Lockdown mode blocks
parts of BPF which makes it impossible for bpftrace to function. Please see 
https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/blob/master/INSTALL.md#disable-lockdown
for more details on lockdown and how to disable it.
```

Which leads me to the following instructions

```
1.  Disable secure boot in UEFI.
```

As far as I can tell, there's no UEFI with VirtualBox.

```
2.    Disable validation using mokutil, run the following command, reboot and follow the prompt.

$ sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```

This results in

```
EFI variables are not supported on this system
```

And

```
3. Use the SysRQ+x key combination to temporarily lift lockdown (until next boot)
```

Can't find how to do this under VirtualBox.

Any tips?

**edit** Apparently, @Qeole installed the same VM I did and didn't get the issue. Something must have gone wrong in my install. I tried with another VM and it now seems to work.

Leaving the issue open so that people can find this resolution.

Comment: Could you double-check that lockdown is actually set? `dmesg | grep -i lockdown`. What image are you running in VirtualBox? If lockdown is set from boot command line, maybe just change that command.

Comment: `dmesg | grep -i lockdown` => empty output. Using image https://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu-mate/ (19.10), but I'm willing to change (or install from iso) if you can suggest a better one. Can't find anything related to lockdown in `/etc/defaults/grub`.

Comment: Hmm that's strange, I would expect a dmesg log about it. bpftrace apparently takes the info from `/sys/kernel/security/lockdown`, which is likely at `none integrity [confidentiality]` in your case. Anyway. Ubuntu 19.10 had lockdown in confidentiality by default when it came out, but they [changed that](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/eoan/+source/linux/+bug/1868626) and it should be integrity with kernel `5.3.0-46-generic` or later. What kernel are you running? If older, any chance you could update it? I have no idea if the SysRQ key can be passed to a VM.

Comment: There's no `/sys/kernel/security/lockdown` in this VM. Running `5.3.0-18-generic` which may be the issue. I'll update. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now running  `5.3.0-51-generic`, same error message, still no `/sys/kernel/security/lockdown`. Should I attempt with a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 or another distro?

Comment: For the file, in fact it's [not used with Ubuntu](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/blob/7cc0106de4075859f20a97ae9c9472738ef3f707/src/lockdown.cpp#L76), my bad. Probably because its creation wasn't backported as part of lockdown on 19.10 (although 20.04 seems to have it). Hmm that's strange. Have you been able to perform any other BPF operation? Does your kernel has the `CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL` option set? FWIW I didn't have issues with BPF with Ubuntu server 20.04 in a VM, so fresh install should work as a last resort. Not sure what's going on with your VM :(.

Comment: For what it's worth I downloaded the image you pointed to (Ubuntu mate 19.10 from osboxes.org running in VirtualBox), but I could not reproduce the issue. In my case bpftrace works, be it installed from Ubuntu repo or built from source :/.

Comment: Well, it works with a fresh install of 20.04. No clue what happened. Thanks for your help.